# Custom node repulsion in a force-based layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Is there a way to make d3 understand the custom forces that I want to apply to some nodes of my force-based graph ? For example in this fiddle : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoperel/Y2LKG/) I have created 3 nodes that I want to be grouped in a rectangle, plus another one that should be outside of this group, except it doesn't because D3 has no way of knowing that.

Here is the code that allows me to position the nodes and the group :

```
function positionAll() {
    positionGroups(d3.selectAll('.myrect'));
}

function positionGroups(data) {
    var groupBoundaries=[];
    data.each(function(d,i) {
        var boundaries = positionRect.call(this,d);
        if (d.group !== undefined) {
            if (!groupBoundaries[d.group]) {
                groupBoundaries[d.group]=[];
            }
            groupBoundaries[d.group].push(boundaries);
        }
    });

    d3.forEach(groupBoundaries, function(boundaries, currentGroup) {
        var topBoundary =    d3.min(boundaries, function(coord) { return coord.y1; }) - 10;
        var rightBoundary =  d3.max(boundaries, function(coord) { return coord.x2; }) + 10;
        var bottomBoundary = d3.max(boundaries, function(coord) { return coord.y2; }) + 10;
        var leftBoundary =   d3.min(boundaries, function(coord) { return coord.x1; }) - 10;

        d3.select('.group').filter(function(group) { return group.name === currentGroup; })
            .attr("x",leftBoundary)
            .attr("y",topBoundary)
            .attr("width",rightBoundary-leftBoundary)
            .attr("height",bottomBoundary-topBoundary);
    });
};

function positionRect(d) {
    var x = d.x || 0;
    var y = d.y || 0;

    d3.select(this)
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", y);

    return {x1: x, y1: y, x2: x+this.getBBox().width, y2: y+this.getBBox().height};
};
```

Of course I could calculate the position of the off-group nodes manually, but then I wouldn't really make advantage of the force layout.

Comment: For specific layouts like this it may be better not to use the force layout. However, if you search for constrained force layout you should be able to find something that may help.

Comment: What do you suggest would be a good layout for a graph like this with potentially many concurrent forces ? I thought it was the purpose of the force layout to solve such constraints.

Comment: It sounds like you could use a force layout for part of the nodes, or possibly have several force layouts.